# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 303]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, train-test-split

Hey guys I'm dealing with a small dataset for my school project, I'm pissed with this error. I am not good at python so let me explain;

This dataset(Heart Disease UCI) has 303 data in it and %53/%47 balanced, she told me to make it balanced as %50/%50 and to expand a bigger dataset with sampling. As I said I'm not an expert I tried my best but the code may be a mess.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')



data = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')
```

On my "target" I have 165 data 1, 138 data 0. So I wanted them to be equal and 5000 to do what she said. First, I tried to copy them with pandas sample, I did 165 to 5000.

```
numsample = 5000 - Y.value_counts()[1]
copys = veri.query("target == 1").sample(numsample, replace=True, random_state=1)
    
newdata = pd.concat([data, copys], axis=0).sample(frac=1.0, random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So my new data was like this

```
newdata['target'].value_counts()

1    5000
0     138
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

And then I did the oversampling imblearn

```
Ytemp = newdata['target']
Xtemp = newdata.drop('target', axis=1)

from imblearn import over_sampling
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler


ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=0)
X2, Y2 = ros.fit_resample(Xtemp, Ytemp)

newdata = pd.concat([X2, Y2], axis=1)
```

And I did what I wanted to do, I do not know if its proper way or not

```
newdata['target'].value_counts()

1    5000
0    5000
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

When I try the train_test_split function this happens

```
X2_train, X2_test, Y2_train, Y2_test = train_test_split(X2, Y2, test_size=0.2, stratify=Y, random_state=0)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-4523092e6077> in <module>()
----> 1 X2_train, X2_test, Y2_train, Y2_test = train_test_split(X2, Y2, test_size=0.2, stratify=Y, random_state=0)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    331         raise ValueError(
    332             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 333             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    334         )
    335 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 303]
```

I have a look at the internet about the error but couldn't figure it out, help please thank you already

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of hearts.csv? You can change the data, it would make reproducing the problem easier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.